# Does the weak formulation have a unique solution?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Recently I was reading a paper by Prof. Brenner. In this paper I encountered a problem of weak formulation, Its statement is as follows: find a function $\phi\in H^1(\Omega)$ with $(\phi,1)=0$ such that $$(\nabla\times\phi,\varepsilon^{-1}\nabla\times\varphi)=(f,\varphi)\quad\text{for all }\varphi\in H^1(\Omega),$$
where $(,)$ denotes the $L_2$ inner product, $\varepsilon$ is a bounded positive function and $(f,1)=0$.
I would like to know whether the function $\phi$ solved here is unique?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I wanted to use the Lax-Milgram theorem but I failed. I learned from Remark2.6 in this [article](https://ins.uni-bonn.de/media/public/publication-media/BGS_2017.pdf?pk=1436) by Brenner that this solution is unique, but I still cannot prove it.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that there is another important condition, that is $(f,1)=0$.